# Downloading Attachment from Exchange Server using SSIS package deployed on another Server

Tags: csv, ssis, exchange-server, email-client

I have built an SSIS package which reads CSV from certain folder. But now I need to download same csv from exchange server.Also Outlook is not installed on my machine. Will I be able to download CSV from exchange server and how ? Thanks!

Comment: You need a step (it can be a script task inside SSIS or it can be an EXE file or Powershell or whatever) that first downloads the file. Here's the first link that came up when I googled it: http://sqlandbilearning.blogspot.com.au/2014/07/download-email-attachment-using-ssis.html

Comment: Thanks it was helpful. i found another link https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/04/19/programmatically-read-email-from-an-exchange-sever-mailbox/ but your link points to SSIS so i will go through script task way.

Comment: I normally recommend you do it externally to SSIS as I've had issues with the script editor and it can be difficult to debug so I suggest you do it in whatever platform you are comfortable with.

Comment: If i am able to make the given script work..Is there any other problem which discourages me from using this strategy according to you?

Comment: Personally I prefer an external script like powershell because it doesn't require a special tool like SSDT to edit, and it's a little easier to unit test. I've had problems with SSDT in the past (installing new / different VS versions can mess it up). But basically, if the SSIS based script works for you - go for it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that link you gave worked for me and i changed it to suit my requirements.Thanks!

Comment: But now I am facing different issue for which i have posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973655/ssis-one-csv-file-out-of-3-getting-read?noredirect=1#comment76922730_44973655 detailing the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have used some of the code from the link http://sqlandbilearning.blogspot.com.au/2014/07/download-email-attachment-using-ssis.html but i have added some new code for removing TCP binding error using ServicePointManager as well as added search filter for retrieving specific emails and this code also takes care of multiple attachment from different emails to be saved on file system.

```
public void Main()
        {
            string filePath = "";
            string fileName = "";
            List<SearchFilter> searchFilterCollection = new List<SearchFilter>();
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime beginRecievedTime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 7, 55, 0);
            DateTime finishRecievedTime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 8, 15, 0);
            EmailMessage latestEmail = null;

            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

                ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
                service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                //service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password");

                service.Url = new Uri("");


                //  10 mails per page in DESC order
                ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
                view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending);
                searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, "Scheduled search"));
                SearchFilter greaterthanfilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, beginRecievedTime);
                searchFilterCollection.Add(greaterthanfilter);
                SearchFilter lessthanfilter = new SearchFilter.IsLessThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, finishRecievedTime);
                searchFilterCollection.Add(lessthanfilter);
                SearchFilter filter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, searchFilterCollection);
                //Find mails
                FindItemsResults<Item> fir = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, filter, view);
                Dictionary<EmailMessage, string> emailsMap = new Dictionary<EmailMessage, string>();
                foreach (Item item in fir.Items)
                {
                    item.Load(); //Load the entire message with attachment
                    EmailMessage email = item as EmailMessage;
                    if (email != null)
                    {
                        if (email.HasAttachments == true && email.Attachments.Count == 1)
                        {
                            if (email.Subject.StartsWith("Scheduled search") == true)
                            {
                                filePath = Path.Combine(Dts.Variables["User::SourceFolderPath"].Value.ToString()
                                                        , email.DateTimeReceived.Date.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy") + "_" +
                                                        email.Attachments[0].Name);
                                // fileName = email.DateTimeReceived.Date.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy") + "_" +
                                //   email.Attachments[0].Name.ToString();
                                emailsMap.Add(email, filePath);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (emailsMap.Count > 0) {
                    foreach (var item in emailsMap) {
                        //Save attachment
                        EmailMessage email = item.Key;
                        filePath = item.Value;
                            FileAttachment fileAttachment = email.Attachments[0] as FileAttachment;
                            fileAttachment.Load(filePath);
                        string extractPath = Dts.Variables["User::SourceFolderPath"].Value.ToString() + "\\" + email.Attachments[0].Name;
                        System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(filePath, extractPath);
                        fileName = Dts.Variables["User::SourceFolderPath"].Value.ToString() + "\\" + email.DateTimeReceived.Date.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy") + "_" +
                          email.Attachments[0].Name.ToString();
                        if (File.Exists(fileName))
                        {
                            File.Delete(fileName);
                        }
                    }
            }

               // Dts.Variables["User::SourceFileName"].Value = fileName;

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            catch(System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
            {
                if (Dts.Variables.Locked == true)
                {
                    Dts.Variables.Unlock();
                }
                //An error occurred.
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Error occured", ex.Message, String.Empty, 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
            }
        }
```